# Glade 3 imports not working for both gtk and gi

Tags: python, glade

```
import gtk

class Buglump:

  def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
    print "quit with cancel"
    gtk.main_quit()

  def on_gtk_quit_activate(self, menuitem, data=None):
    print "quit from menu"
    gtk.main_quit()

  def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "tutorial-1.glade"
    self.builder = gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main = Buglump()
  gtk.main()
```

So I am using this source code to attempt to use the GUI builder glade, however I keep running into many different errors and am doubting if I am even taking the right approach. From my understanding, you generate this code in a different python shell and it will produce whatever you have built in glade. However I keep running into errors, the current one being :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtk'
```

I am seeking guidance of how to move forward using glade, I am very new to python so I apologize if this is not a good question. I can not find any way to use this program from anywhere I have looked online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an app in development, I have following below; perhaps you can use something similar.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk, Gdk as gdk, GLib, GObject as gobject
```